# Как слить многомерные массивы с сохранением ключей одного из них?

Tags: php, массивы

Задачи состоит в том, чтобы ключами нового массива были значения ключей первого массива (ключи не начинаются с 0), а значениями были значения первого и второго массивов.
Массивы выглядит так:

```
Value_indicator ([10] => 56, [11] => 33, [12] => 45),
Norma_indcicator ([0] => 1, [1] => 0, [2] => 2).
```

Новый массив должен выглядеть так:

```
Result ([10] => 56 => 1, [11] => 33 => 0, [12] => 45 => 2)
```

Comment: У вас в примере нет ключей, только индексы. Новый же массив вообще вызывает вопрос - это как? [10] => 56 => 1 - вы хотите присвоить 10му элементу массива подмассив с индексом 56 в который передать значение 1? Или в ячейку с идексом 10 положить подмассив значений [56, 1]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем ясен - буду предполагать, что необходимо каждое значение первого массива преобразовывать в подмассив с добавлением в него значения из второго массива в соответствии с индексом.

```
$a = array(
'10' => 56,
'11' => 33,
'12' => 45
);

$b = array(1,2,3);

$c = array();

$i = 0;

array_walk($a, function ($value, $key) use (&$c, $b, &$i) {
    $c[$key] = [$value, $b[$i]];
    $i++;
});
```

[пример](http://jdoodle.com/a/vFp)